# Exactly once semantics in Spark Streaming Direct Approach

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Spark's official documentation says the Direct based approach involves using SimpleConsumer API which doesn't use Zookeeper to store offsets and instead storing the offsets using Spark's metadata checkpointing.  The documentation also says Direct based approach guarantees exactly once semantics.

When we enable Spark's metadata checkpointing using ssc.checkpoint("directory"), we never specify the interval.

Now, for each microbatch, triggered after the microbatch interval, the driver sends the offsets to each task which retrieve data for the corresponding Kafka partition.

**Questions**:

1. Considering the corresponding data retrieved from Kafka for the specified offsets is not persisted in Spark and only the offsets are stored in Spark as part of its metadata checkpointing, doesn't the timing of the checkpointing matter as it directly influences exactly once or at least/most once semantics? Does it happen as soon as the microbatch is triggered and directstream retrieves data from kafka or does it happen at the end of the microbatch completion?
2. Also, what do the offsets store as part of metadata checkpointing signify? Does it specify the offsets processed or the offsets yet to be processed?

Answer (score 0):

Checkpointing is one of the options out of three [[Checkpoints](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#checkpoints), [Kafka itself](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#kafka-itself), [Your own data store]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#your-own-data-store), Checkpointing has several drawbacks, and cannot guarantee exactly-once unless your transaction is idempotent.

The documentation warns you about Checkpointing as below :

> So if you want the equivalent of exactly-once semantics, you must
>   either store offsets after an idempotent output, or store offsets in
>   an atomic transaction alongside output.

See [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#storing-offsets) section of the official documentation describing the three option in detail

Comment: Exactly. That's what I was thinking of too. I mean Direct based approach with checkpointing enabled alone cannot help in exactly once semantics as that involves saving processed data and offsets atomically. And since metadata checkpointing in spark and saving your processed data using .saveas*** are two discrete steps, it cannot guarantee exactly once semantics. Now, when you say handling idempotency when checkpointing is enabled (ignoring other problems of checkpointing) can guarantee exactly once semantics, do you mean that metadata checkpointing occurs only after a microbatch is complete?

Comment: I say that because idempotency comes out of at least once semantics as a developer responsibility which would mean metadata checkpointing happening "after" each microbatch execution so that in cases where the driver goes down immediately after the microbatch execution is complete but before the metadata checkpointing is complete implying that restarting the driver would mean re-executing the particular offset as it was not saved in metadata checkpointing the last time. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @SheelPancholi, You can actually control the checkpointing to happen before or after, using a parameter - "Checkpointing can be eager or lazy per eager flag of checkpoint operator. Eager checkpointing is the default checkpointing and happens immediately when requested. Lazy checkpointing does not and will only happen when an action is executed" - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-checkpointing.html